# Solving Reaction Diffusion Equation $u_t = Du_{xx}-\gamma u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm having problems with solving a reaction-diffusion equation, since I barely have any experience with PDEs.

I know:

$u_t = Du_{xx}$ with $u(x,0)=u_0$ is solved by the so-called fundamental solution: $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi D t}}\int e^{- \frac{(x-y)^2}{4Dt}}u_0 \, dy$

But my question is, what if I have $u_t = Du_{xx}-\gamma u$. What is the solution of it then? $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've tried using:
$v := e^{\gamma t} u$

The derivative of $v$ w.r.t. $t$ is then:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v = e^ {\gamma t}(Du_{xx}-\gamma u) + \gamma e^{\gamma t} u = e^{\gamma t}Du_{xx}$$
So if I solve $v_t = e^{\gamma t}Du_{xx}$, then $u$ would just be $u = e^{-\gamma t}v$.
Unfortunately, I struggle with solving $v_t$. Does anyone know how I should proceed?

Comment: You've practically solved it already.  $e^{\gamma t} D u_{xx} = D v_{xx}$, so the last equation you wrote down is a diffusion equation for $v$.

Comment: Why does $e^{\gamma t}Du_{xx}=Dv_{xx}$ hold? So if it does hold, then $v_t = Dv_{xx}$, hence $v= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi Dt}} \int e^{- \frac{(x-y)^2}{4Dt}} u_0 \, dy$ if $v(x,0)=u_0$. And thus, $u=e^{-\gamma t}\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi Dt}} \int e^{- \frac{(x-y)^2}{4Dt}} u_0 \, dy$. Is that correct?

Comment: It holds because $Dv_{xx} = D \partial_x^2 v = D \partial_x^2 (e^{\gamma t} u) = D e^{\gamma t} u_{xx} = e^{\gamma t} D u_{xx}$.  So your subsequent analysis is exactly right.

Comment: Another question. Let $S_t:=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi D t}}\int e^{- \frac{(x-y)^2}{4Dt}}dy$. If I check if $u = e^{-\gamma t}S_tu_0$ is actually the solution of $u_t = Du_{xx}-\gamma u$, then I take the derivative of $u$ w.r.t. $t$, which is $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u=-\gamma e^{-\gamma t}S_tu_0+e^{-\gamma t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(S_tu_0)=-\gamma e^{-\gamma t}S_tu_0 + e^{-\gamma t}Du_{xx} = e^{-\gamma t}Du_{xx}- \gamma u$.... So tbh, I don't understand this now. I mean everything made sense, except for this. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: You made several mistakes in the latest comment.  First, you don't *multiply* $S_T$ by $u_0$ to get a solution $u$, you have to put $u_0$ *inside* the integral (because $u_0 = u_0(x)$ is dependent on $x$).

Second, the string of equalities you wrote has many errors.  I think you are getting confused by your notation and conflating solutions of the diffusion equation and the reaction-diffusion equation.  I suggest going through the computations more explicitly.  The solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fourier transform to get an algebraic equation of second order, then return by iversing the transform.